# Outputting data into a file

Tags: python, numpy

I inputted a file into my code, and then added 2 to all of the second columns of that file. Is there a way to output my new columns into another file? If my explanation isn't clear, I provided an example below.

```
file = 'expansionex.csv'
cepheid = genfromtxt('expansionex.csv', delimiter = ',')

newcolumn = cepheid[:,1] + 2


?output file: cepheid[:,0], newcolumn
```

Answer (score 1):

If i have correctly understood I think that you need something like that:

```
savetxt(outputfile_name, newcolumn, fmt='%.18e', delimiter=' ', newline='\n', header='', footer='', comments='# ', encoding=None)
```

I suggest you to see in deep the numpy documentation for the parameter explication and for some examples!
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt

```
import numpy as np
a = np.loadtxt('filename.csv', delimiter = ',')
a[:,1] += 2
np.savetxt("newfilename.csv", delimiter = ',')
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for [pandas.to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)?